# Send boolean between UIViewControllers using NotificationCenter and Observer

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 classes and I try to use NotificationsCenter and Observers to send a boolean.
If the boolean is sent correctly then I want to navigate on a ViewController.
But unfortunately my function from Observer (`checkIsUserFromChecklist`) is not triggering for some reasons.
Here is my code:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let isAccessedFromChecklistVC = Notification.Name(rawValue: "isAccessedFromChecklistVC")
}

// Class where I want to check if the boolean is changed
class ChecklistVC: UIViewController {

    var isAccessedFromChecklist = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .isAccessedFromChecklistVC, object: isAccessedFromChecklist)
    }
    //…
    //…
    //…
}

// Class where I want to get the value of the boolean

class FullscreenImageVC: UIViewController {

    var isAccessedFromChecklistVC = false

    // Remove observer from memory after we use it
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        createObservers()
    }

    func createObservers(){

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(checkIfIsAccessedFromChecklist),
                                               name: .isAccessedFromChecklistVC,
                                               object: nil)
    }

    @objc func checkIfIsAccessedFromChecklist(_ notification: Notification){

        if let object = notification.object as? Bool{
            print("Object status: \(object)") // Is never entering here.

            isAccessedFromChecklistVC = object
        }
    }

    func navigateToChecklist(){

        if isAccessedFromChecklistVC == true {
            let checklistVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChecklistVC") as! ChecklistVC
            self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([self.navigationController!.viewControllers.first!, checklistVC], animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks if you read this.

Comment: Your observing view controller is not observing when the post is made because the coding of the notification itself is fine. Btw, you couldn't find a better way for these two view controllers to communicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that this post occurs

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .isAccessedFromChecklistVC, object: isAccessedFromChecklist)
```

before `FullscreenImageVC`  vc registers as an observer

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                 selector: #selector(checkIfIsAccessedFromChecklist),
                 name: .isAccessedFromChecklistVC
                 object: nil)
```

So make sure you do the post when the second vc is active